# How I can export to excel a tree hierarchy using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a class:

```
class Node{
private Node parent;
private List<Node> children;
...
}
```

How I can export a tree of it's items to excel using Apache POI for getting document like this (I need to shift only first column in table):

```
A
 B
  C
 D
 E
  F
   G
```

Comment: I might be wrong but that output looks like a list of Trees rather than a single Tree. (I say this because it looks like A,C,D, and E are at the same level, but it doesn't look like they have a common parent). Is there a root for the tree output?

Comment: thanks :) yes, parent is single

Comment: You can use the `XSSFSheet` and `XSSFWorkbook` classes for help. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution - merging. Have a nice day. Thanks.

Looks like this:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36352_01/epm.1112/disclosure_mgmt_admin/new_files/image002.jpg

My solution with merging:

```
private int createHierarchy(Sheet sheet, Node node, int currentRowIdx, int nodeLevel) {
    if(node.getParent() == null){
        sheet.setColumnWidth(8, 1000);
        Row row = sheet.createRow(currentRowIdx);
        row.createCell(nodeLevel).setCellValue(node.getName());
        row.createCell(9).setCellValue(node.getValue());
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(currentRowIdx, currentRowIdx, nodeLevel, 8));
        nodeLevel++;
    }

    for (Node node : node.getChildren()) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(++currentRowIdx);
        row.createCell(nodeLevel).setCellValue(node.getName());
        row.createCell(9).setCellValue(node.getValue());
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(currentRowIdx, currentRowIdx, nodeLevel, 8));
        currentRowIdx = createHierarchy(sheet, node, currentRowIdx, nodeLevel+1);
    }

    return currentRowIdx;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry I didn't quite understand what you were looking for, but I'm glad it worked! Also welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to accept the answer that worked best for you, this way other people can get to answering questions that haven't been resolved yet.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to create a `NodeWriter` class that essentially writes the Node onto an Excel Spreadsheet:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class NodeWriter {
    public void write(Node tree, String filePathName) {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Tree");
        writeHelp(0, 1, tree, sheet);
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePathName)) {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void writeHelp(int indent, int rowNum, Node tree, XSSFSheet sheet) {
        if (sheet.getRow(rowNum) != null) {
            writeHelp(indent, rowNum+1, tree, sheet);
        } else {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(indent);
            cell.setCellValue(tree.getNodeName());
            for (Node child : tree.getChildren()) {
                writeHelp(indent + 1, rowNum + 1, child, sheet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've made some assumptions about your `Node` class. This solution ensures that you create a new Row and don't overwrite existing rows (as you would if that `if` loop wasn't there in `writeHelp`).

Comment: But in this case I need nodeName in same column. And I don't know how to trim them left part according to level of node.

Comment: When I look at my excel document I see the same tree structure you suggested; what does it look like for you/ what should it look like?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36352_01/epm.1112/disclosure_mgmt_admin/new_files/image002.jpg

Comment: For reference the `.createCell(indent)` creates a cell at the column number specified by indent

Comment: How can I set width of cell?

Comment: I need other columns, but with fixed position

Comment: My solution - merging. Have a nice day. Thanks.